# Messenger program for QQ on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 11.04 and now I want open a QQ account with Pidgin. Pidgin
can open Yahoo and MSN for me but will not work for QQ.

Could someone help? Or does anyone know of other messenger for QQ in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the built-in QQ support in Pidgin broke recently when QQ updated their version. I've been testing out the [libqq-pidgin](http://code.google.com/p/libqq-pidgin/), and it seems stable enough for now. It supports the QQ2010 protocol. I haven't had a chance to look through the source code yet.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is having a virtual windows to run QQ (with nothing else in it). Not because there are not options in Linux, but because QQ is basically a virus. It will read your hdd searching for content that will be passed to other search engines; will also filter words used in the communication (with unknown targets) and others.

Think twice before using it for a serious communication or in a partition that it can access other files.

Answer (score 1):

I've read on the [QQ International official page on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/qqinternational) that they're rolling out a Web-based version of the QQ client (in English).

It's called [QQ Chat](http://qqchat.qq.com) and it looks like you need to run it from your own Facebook account.

I am a Linux user as well and I welcomed this news because I'd really like to use QQ on my box and so far the only option was either a virtual machine or WINE emulation (I've succeeded many times on different Ubuntu-based distributions).

I don't know where the user above got the news that QQ is a virus but I've been using it for years with no problems. Actually, his post got me paranoid and I tested my Windows QQ International copy with different AVs... no problems at all. Please do some research before making other people scared :)

Comment: He didn't say it was a virus, just that it acts in similar ways.